# Task Scheduler wait until first logon of the day but thereafter guarantee only run at 1 hour intervals

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a task in task scheduler to run every hour and pop up a dialogue that lets the user pick from a list what activity they are currently working on. These tasks need to be spaced evenly throughout the day to sample how frequently each task is being worked on - this will determine what % of the user's time is dedicated to each task.

I am trying to run

- On a daily schedule
- Starting at 8AM (or logon - whichever is later)
- With random delay to the start time
- Every hour

The issue is, if I set the task to "retry if scheduled start is missed" then my samples are not 1 hour apart which messes up my statistical analysis

I can't work out how to get the task to start a random amount of time < 1hr after startup and thereafter at exact 1 hour intervals. If the task is missed it must not run again, I want to log "Unknown" and resume the next hour.

---

My current settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the "General" tab, do you have "run whether user is logged on or not" checked?

Comment: A task cannot modify its trigger, which seems to be what you're asking for. I think that you should settle for something like "what the user was during on the half-hour mark". And have you considered lunch-time, smoking time, not mentioning toilet-time? I think you're going to get a lot of complaints with this scheme.

Comment: @harrymc sorry in the settings I meant to check "delay task for up to (random delay)" set to 1 hour. So I don't think I'm asking to modify start time unless I am and don't realise it. The user in this case is voluntary, it is a self reflection tool so capturing any activity is valuable. But agreed this technique could be misused. Asking for average over last half an hour is easier to mess up the reporting and stats, this method works best with random instantaneous timestamps evenly spread over a long period.

Answer (score 0):

In Task Manager, opposite click the task and choose "properties". On the "General" tab, do you have "run whether user is logged on or not" checked?

If, it's not checked, it will only run the task if the designated user is logged on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is not checked so it already should run only if the trigger happens when user is logged on. I was having issues the if the user is not logged on when the first trigger is scheduled, then the task will not run at all the whole day.